# Entity Framework (Core), multiple refrences to the same table but different objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an automotive part:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Part (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    PartNumber nvarchar(48) not null,
    Colour nvarchar(100) null,
    Height int null,
    -- etc
)
```

Automotive parts are often interchangeable. You can replace 1 part on your car/truck with OEM part "A" or aftermarket part "B".

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Interchanges (
    Part1 int not null,
    Part2 int not null,
    Notes nvarchar(500) not null,
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Interchanges WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Interchanges_Part1
FOREIGN KEY (Part1) REFERENCES dbo.Part (Id)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Interchanges WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Interchanges_Part2
FOREIGN KEY (Part2) REFERENCES dbo.Part (Id)
```

Note: 1 part can be interchanged with many other parts, and interchanges are two-way in this case.

Now let's pretend I've two parts (part number A, and B), and they are interchanged with one another.

When I instantiate part A I'd like it to have a collection of Interchanges. In this case the collection would have one object. That object would have the interchange notes and a part object instance whose part number is B.

Similarly, if I edit part B, it's collection would have an object which has the interchange notes and a part instance whose part number is A.

Is there an elegant way to model this?

Is there a name for this pattern that I can Google?

With the SQL above when I load part A it has a ICollection (created with the Entity Framework Power Tools addon). That interchange object has the interchange notes, an instance of Part B, and also an instance of Part A.

Answer (score 1):

In the relational model there's no first-class way to model a [Symmetric Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation), so you either have to handle it in application code, or store it as two separate rows (A,B, 'A and B are interchangable') and (B,A, 'A and B are interchangable')

If you add rows for the inverse of each relation, then the EF model is simple, as Part only needs one Navigation Property.

Here's a Code First model version of what (I think) you are looking for:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    public class Part
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Interchange> Interchanges { get; } = new HashSet<Interchange>();

    }

    public class Interchange
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order =1 )]
        public int FromPartId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int ToPartId { get; set; }

        public virtual Part FromPart { get; set; }
        public virtual Part ToPart { get; set; }
    }



    class Db : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Interchange> Interchanges { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Part>()
                        .HasMany(p => p.Interchanges)
                        .WithRequired()
                        .HasForeignKey(i => i.FromPartId)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }


    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Log = a => Console.WriteLine(a);

                var A = db.Parts.Create();
                A.PartNumber = "A";

                var B = db.Parts.Create();
                B.PartNumber = "B";

                A.Interchanges.Add(new Interchange() {  FromPart = A, ToPart = B });
                B.Interchanges.Add(new Interchange() { FromPart = B, ToPart = A });

                db.Parts.Add(A);
                db.Parts.Add(B);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

                var A = db.Parts.Where(p => p.PartNumber == "A").Single();

                Console.WriteLine($"Part {A.PartNumber} has {A.Interchanges.Count()} Interchanges");

                Console.WriteLine($"Part {A.PartNumber} is interchangable with {A.Interchanges.First().ToPart.PartNumber}");
            }
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding two rows for each one interchange is what I've currently done. I add a row for A -> B, and a second row for B -> A.

Comment: Even if it were two separate rows, I would have to remove one foreign key I assume? Part1 would still be a foreign key pointing to the part that has been interchanged, column Part2 would not be a foreign key, it would represent the part we're interchanging with? This would mean that Entity Framework would not automatically load instances of Part representing the parts which column Part2 holds the id of?

Comment: Both Foreign Keys stay.  But you would only have a Navigation Property for one of them.

Comment: But what option do I have? Two foreign keys to the same table will load an ICollection where each record has two part objects (one of which is redundant because it's the part which owns the collection in the first place).

Comment: The Foreign Keys are on Interchanges.  There are no Foreign Keys on Part.  "Foregn Key" means property that carries the key value of another entity.  The ICollection properties are Navigation Properties and they are optional.  Also they are not automatically loaded.  They are loaded when you explicitly request or if you have Lazy Loading configured.

Comment: David: I know what foreign keys are. I didn't say there was a foreign key on table Part. If I instantiate the Part (C#) with PartNumber "A" (see first post), I'd like that part to have an ICollection<Interchanges> navigation property. The one object in that collection would have a Notes property and ONE instance of a Part object whose PartNumber is B. Is this possible? Let's assume Interchanges contains a record A->B and B->A as discussed previously.

Comment: Yes this is possible.  See the new example in the answer.